# I was decided to join all of the 3 tables into 1, but it shows data not found, how can i solve this problem?

Tags: sql, oracle

```
SELECT
  Driver.DriverID,
  Driver.DriverName,
  Driver.DriverContactNo,
  Driver.VehiclePlatNo,
  PartTime.PartTimeID,
  PartTime.WorkingHourperDay,
  PartTime.PaidByHour,
  PartTime.LicenseType,
  FullTime.FullTimeID,
  FullTime.ContactPeriod,
  FullTime.DrivingExperience,
  FullTime.Age
FROM Driver
INNER JOIN PartTime
  ON Driver.DriverID = PartTime.DriverID
INNER JOIN FullTime
  ON Driver.DriverID = FullTime.DriverID;
```

May I know how to solve this?

Comment: Show us some example data from each table; make it the related data - for example, pull driver ID 1, parttime driver ID 1 and fulltime driver id 1

Answer (score 0):

You should work on reformatting your question so that it's easier to read.

I believe the problem that you're having is that you're using two inner joins, but there is never any data that overlaps. Basically, you're looking for someone who is both a part time driver AND a full-time driver. My guess is you're looking for the "OR" of those, not the "AND." To fix this you need to change your inner joins to left joins.

Consider this as a way to rewrite your query:

```
SELECT
  Driver.DriverID,
  Driver.DriverName,
  Driver.DriverContactNo,
  Driver.VehiclePlatNo,
  PartTime.PartTimeID,
  PartTime.WorkingHourperDay,
  PartTime.PaidByHour,
  PartTime.LicenseType,
  FullTime.FullTimeID,
  FullTime.ContactPeriod,
  FullTime.DrivingExperience,
  FullTime.Age
FROM Driver
  LEFT JOIN PartTime
    ON Driver.DriverID = PartTime.DriverID
  LEFT JOIN FullTime
    ON Driver.DriverID = FullTime.DriverID;
```